# Embedding image in html email from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to build an email that has both text and an image (chart from Excel) using HTML code. I merged code I found online.

This is what I have so far for the image:

```
FirstChartPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Current Credit Usage.png"
ChartName = "Current Credit Usage.png"
'add the image in hidden manner, position at 0 will make it hidden
.Attachments.Add FirstChartPath, olByValue, 0

'Now add it to the Html body using image name

'change the src property to 'cid:your image filename'
'it will be changed to the correct cid when its sent.
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>CURRENT CREDIT USAGE:</B><br>" _
  & "<img src='cid:Current Credit Usage.png'" & "width='500' height='200'>"
  '& "<br>Best Regards, <br>Sumit</font></span>"
```

I get an "X" in the image saying the linked image cannot be displayed.

> "The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location"

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between the source file and the width. Not sure if even HTML is *that* forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

changed it to:

```
'Second part with the charts
    FirstChartPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Current Credit Usage.jpg"
    ChartName = "Current Credit Usage.jpg"
      'add the image in hidden manner, position at 0 will make it hidden
    .Attachments.Add FirstChartPath, olByValue, 0

    'Now add it to the Html body using image name

    'change the src property to 'cid:your image filename'
    'it will be changed to the correct cid when its sent.
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>CURRENT CREDIT USAGE:</B><br>" _
                & "<img src='" & FirstChartPath & "'width='500' height='200'>"
                '& "<br>Best Regards, <br>Sumit</font></span>"
```

and worked, i was missing one " ' "

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image as an attachment and set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property:
[Including Pictures in an Outlook Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195207/including-pictures-in-an-outlook-email)