VBA auto emailing not allowing signature line image to send
Sub ExportAndEmailWorksheetsAsPDF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pdfFile As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim emailList(1 To 8) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim signature As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim signaturePath As String

    ' Define the folder path where the PDFs will be saved
    folderPath = "C:\Users\TWham\OneDrive - mulldrlg.com\Operations\Production Department\Production Specialist\TASKS\2) ENTER SWD STATEMENTS\SWD OUTGOING" ' <-- Change this to your desired folder path

    ' Define the email addresses (replace with actual emails)
    emailList(1) = "risa@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(2) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(3) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(4) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(5) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(6) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(7) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"
    emailList(8) = "travisw@mullcompanies.com"

    ' Set up Outlook object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Get the signature file content
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    signaturePath = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\TRAVIS WHAM (TWham@MullDrilling.com).htm"
    If fso.FileExists(signaturePath) Then
        signature = fso.GetFile(signaturePath).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll
    Else
        MsgBox "Signature file not found at: " & signaturePath & vbNewLine & _
               "Please check the signature name and location.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Loop through each worksheet
    For i = 1 To 8
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        pdfFile = ws.Name & ".pdf"

        ' Export the worksheet as a PDF
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=pdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

        ' Create a new email
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = emailList(i)
            .Subject = "SWD Report - " & ws.Name
            .HTMLBody = "Please find your SWD report attached. " & "<br><br>" & signature
            .Attachments.Add pdfFile
            .Send ' Sends the email (use .Display if you want to preview before sending)
        End With

        ' Clean up
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i

    ' Clean up
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    MsgBox "All worksheets have been exported as PDFs and emailed."
End Sub

Here is the code I'm using to download PDFs and send to various addresses via Outlook. Upon sending, my company logo won't send with the signature line in my email. When I send to myself, the image loads, so I feel as if it's because I'm referencing a location on my computer. PLEASE HELP!!!

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354856/embedding-image-in-html-email-from-excel-vba and linked from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197140/478884
