# Is there a way to start outlook inspector minimized with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Following code starts notepad minimized.

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad")
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Process.Start(psi)
```

I need a vb.net code which starts **outlook inspector** minimized.

or

I need a vb.net code which makes **outlook inspector** minimized before display.

Comment: The answer in that question is not specific to notepad.  Did you try it?  What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Process.Start` - create a new instance of the `Outlook.Application` COM object (add a reference to the Outlook type library).

Comment: Why do you need an inspector to be visible even if it is minimized? Are you manipulating the message body using the Word Object Model?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195207/including-pictures-in-an-outlook-email

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with OutlookSpy? OutlookSpy is a dev tool, it is for you to see things inside Outlook, not for the end users. 2. Outlook images are **always** attachments unless the HTML body refers to an externally hosted image on a web server. 3. No, there isn't one.

Comment: Why? Just use the code from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195207/including-pictures-in-an-outlook-email

Comment: I think I am repeating myself - Outlook does not have inline images. They are always attachments. Take a look for a yourself in OutlookSpy - select a message with an image, click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab.