# Delphi - Using resource in Email rather than image

Tags: email, delphi, outlook, indy

In Delphi, I create emails in HTML using the following code to display a signature in the message:

```
cMsg:= cMsg + ' <img src="BarrysSignature.jpg" '>
```

Which means I need to have the `.jpg` available in the current directory (and distribute it with the executable).

I also use these same signature `.jpg` files elsewhere in my program, but I've loaded them as resources. What would be better in the emails is if I used the resource for the signature in the email, rather than the external `.jpg` picture.

I've tried a few ways of doing this but can't get it working. Any thoughts, please?

Comment: Please substitute "_a few ways_" with actual descriptions.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [@Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70395073/65863), in Indy you would also need to attach the image data to an email (the `TIdMessage` component), assign the attachment's `Content-ID` header (the `TIdMessagePart.ContentID` property), and then refer to that ID in the HTML using a `cid:` URL where needed.

Refer to these blog articles on Indy's website for how to do this:

[HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/)

[New HTML Message Builder class](https://www.indyproject.org/2008/01/16/new-html-message-builder-class/)

I do want to mention one thing, though.  Where the articles talk about using `TIdAttachmentFile` for attachments, you actually don't need to save your image resource to a temporary file at all in this situation.  You can alternatively derive your own class from `TIdAttachment` (let's call it `TIdAttachmentResource`), and have it override the virtual `OpenLoadStream()` and `CloseLoadStream()` methods to return/free a `TResourceStream` to your resource data, respectively (see the source codes for `TIdAttachmentFile` and `TIdAttachmentMemory` for examples).  Then you can simply add `TIdAttachmentResource` objects to the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection as needed, and Indy will be able to encode the email using the image resource directly, no file needed.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, you will need to extract the resource to a temporary file, add the image as an attachment, set its `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property, delete the file. Your HTML body would need to reference the image by its content-id, e.g. `<img src="cid:xyz">`, where "xyz" is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.

See [Including Pictures in an Outlook Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195207/including-pictures-in-an-outlook-email/17197140#17197140)