# How to add picture of specific cells to Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm adding a "Send email" button to a working sheet and want to add a picture to the Outlook email. The picture is a graph which gets updated every week.

It looks like this. I guess I have to make a function somewhere in the body, wherever is suitable for the output:

```vb
Sub Create_Email()

'Define outlook variables
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

'Allocated
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim NextParagraph As String

NextParagraph = vbNewLine & vbNewLine

'Inside the with box is what we send
With OutMail
    .To = "hej@hejsen.com"
    '.cc =
    '.bcc =
    .Subject = "Let us see if this will all show in the subject line"
    .Body = "Good morning everyone," & NextParagraph & "The Monday Morning Report is attached." & NextParagraph & _
                        "Comps are"
    .Display
End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  GetInspector.WordEditor to edit mail object and insert image using MS Word object model and insert picture with [Shapes.AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.shapes.addpicture)

```
Dim myInspector As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim myitem As Object
 
Set myitem = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
Set myInspector = myitem.GetInspector
Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image as file, add it as an attachment, and reference it in the `HTMLBody` property instead of using the plain-text `Body`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197140/332059